# Wordpress - Sub Menu displaying wrong

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Back here again. I'm trying to finish off my navigation on a Wordpress install. I didn't take into account the three tier navigation that I would need.

My first two tiers are displaying as I would like, however the final tier is displaying underneath the 2nd tier. Id like it to display to the right of parent. I've attempted to change multiple lines of code but the entire navigation ends up breaking.

I've created a JS fiddle and removed all but the useful code

https://jsfiddle.net/jackniksmith/6y38jv1g/8/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html ng-app="curriculum" class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->



  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="inner">


        <div id="navigation">
          <nav class="nav-main">
            <div class="menu-menu-main-container">
              <ul id="menu-menu-main" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-138"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-14005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14005"><a href="#">About</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-14017" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14017"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14018"><a href="#">Vision, ethos and mission aims</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14019" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14019"><a href="#">Ofsted Report 2017</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14020" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14020"><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14021"><a href="#">Quotes and Parental Views</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14022"><a href="#">Pupil Leadership</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14023"><a href="#">The Decus Educational Trust</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14024" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14024"><a href="#">Image Gallery</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14026"><a href="#">Parents</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-14025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14025"><a href="#">Attendance</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14027"><a href="#">Letters</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14028" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14028"><a href="#">Letter Bank</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14029"><a href="#">Newsletters and Learning Letters</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14030" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14030"><a href="#">Safeguarding</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14031"><a href="#">Safeguarding</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14032" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14032"><a href="#">Online Safety</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14033"><a href="#">Out of Hours Activities</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14034" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14034"><a href="#">PTA</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14035"><a href="#">Inclusion</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14036" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14036"><a href="#">SEND and Inclusion</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14037" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14037"><a href="#">Anti-Bullying</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14038" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14038"><a href="#">Pupil Premium Checklist</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14039" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14039"><a href="#">Key Information</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14040" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14040"><a href="#">Term Dates</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14041" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14041"><a href="#">Uniform</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14042"><a href="#">Lost Property</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14043"><a href="#">SchoolComms</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14044" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14044"><a href="#">School Menu</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14045"><a href="#">Nursery</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14046"><a href="#">Supporting your child&#8217;s learning</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14047" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14047"><a href="#">Supporting your child&#8217;s learning</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14048" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14048"><a href="#">Useful Websites</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14049"><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <nav class="sub-nav">
            <div class="menu-sub-menu-container">
              <ul id="menu-sub-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1701" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1701"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13879"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13880"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13881" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13881"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-5139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5139"><a href="#">Vacancies</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {   background: #e6eef2; }

header {   background: #FFFFFF;   overflow: auto; }

.inner {   width: 1000px;   margin: 0 auto; }

 .main {   width: 1000px;   margin: 0 auto;   background: #FFFFFF;  
 overflow: auto; }

 .home-section {   padding: 60px 0;   overflow: auto;   position:
 relative; }

 #logo {   width: 250px;   padding: 40px 0;   float: left; }

 #logo-img {   width: 100%; }

 .nav-main {   float: right;   position: relative; }

 .nav-main ul {   text-align: right;   font-size: 18px;   padding-top:
 35px; }

 .nav-main ul li {   display: inline-block;   margin-left: 15px;  
 position: relative; }

 .nav-main ul li a {   color: #666;   text-decoration: none; }

 .nav-main ul ul {   display: none;   position: absolute;   left: 0;  
 width: 150px;   padding: 0;   left: 0;   margin: 0;   text-align:
 left; }

 .nav-main ul ul li {   background: grey;   padding: 5px 10px;  
 margin-left: 0;   z-index: 999999; }

 .nav-main ul ul li a {   padding: 0; }

 .nav-main ul li:hover>ul {   display: block; }

 .sub-nav {   float: right;   clear: right; }

 .sub-nav ul {   text-align: right;   font-size: 14px;   margin: 0 0
 15px 0; }

 .sub-nav ul li {   display: inline-block;   margin-left: 15px; }

 .sub-nav ul li h2 {   font-size: 14px;   font-weight: normal;  
 margin: 0; }

 .sub-nav ul li a {   color: #999;   text-decoration: none; }

 #navigation {   float: right;   width: 50%;   position: absolute;   left: 482px; }
```

For example if you go to Parents > Letters. On hover of letters the third tier will display beneath.

If anyone is able to explain what I am missing I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Jack

Comment: So you just want it above? Then give those UL a z-index. (And make the nonsense value of the `li` - `z-index: 999999` - something a bit more sensible.)

Comment: Hi, I'd like it to the right of the parent element. Changed my Z-Index and it doesn't seem to work ? Thanks

Comment: Then start by changing `left: 0` …

Comment: You have to support IE7? You have to support IE8??

Comment: We don't, I've just had this job dumped on me so I'm learning as I go. The IE stuff must be from the original dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting z-index values on your `<li>`s instead of your `<ul>`s.

Remove the z-index value on your `<li>` and set an index value on your `<ul>` :

```
.nav-main ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You only need this declaration. Since the sub-sub menu is a child of the first one, it'll be above it because it'll have a z-index of 1 as well. Check out this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3) to understand z-index a bit better (there are plenty just like it).

Then, if you want the second sub-menu to show on the left of its parent, simply add these lines :

```
.nav-main ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #e6eef2;
}

header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

.home-section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  float: left;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-main {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main ul {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.nav-main ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-main ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-main ul ul li {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-main ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.nav-main ul ul ul li {
  background: red;
}

.nav-main ul ul li a {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-main ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sub-nav {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

.sub-nav ul {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.sub-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.sub-nav ul li h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-nav ul li a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 482px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html ng-app="curriculum" class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->



  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="inner">
        

        <div id="navigation">
          <nav class="nav-main">
            <div class="menu-menu-main-container">
              <ul id="menu-menu-main" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-138"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-14005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14005"><a href="#">About</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-14017" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14017"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14018"><a href="#">Vision, ethos and mission aims</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14019" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14019"><a href="#">Ofsted Report 2017</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14020" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14020"><a href="#">Governance</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14021"><a href="#">Quotes and Parental Views</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14022"><a href="#">Pupil Leadership</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14023"><a href="#">The Decus Educational Trust</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14024" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14024"><a href="#">Image Gallery</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14026"><a href="#">Parents</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-14025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14025"><a href="#">Attendance</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14027"><a href="#">Letters</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14028" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14028"><a href="#">Letter Bank</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14029"><a href="#">Newsletters and Learning Letters</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14030" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14030"><a href="#">Safeguarding</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14031"><a href="#">Safeguarding</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14032" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14032"><a href="#">Online Safety</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14033"><a href="#">Out of Hours Activities</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14034" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14034"><a href="#">PTA</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14035"><a href="#">Inclusion</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14036" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14036"><a href="#">SEND and Inclusion</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14037" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14037"><a href="#">Anti-Bullying</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14038" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14038"><a href="#">Pupil Premium Checklist</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14039" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14039"><a href="#">Key Information</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14040" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14040"><a href="#">Term Dates</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14041" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14041"><a href="#">Uniform</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14042"><a href="#">Lost Property</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14043"><a href="#">SchoolComms</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14044" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14044"><a href="#">School Menu</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14045"><a href="#">Nursery</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14046"><a href="#">Supporting your child&#8217;s learning</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-14047" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14047"><a href="#">Supporting your child&#8217;s learning</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-14048" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14048"><a href="#">Useful Websites</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14049"><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <nav class="sub-nav">
            <div class="menu-sub-menu-container">
              <ul id="menu-sub-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1701" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1701"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13879"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13880"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-13881" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13881"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-5139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5139"><a href="#">Vacancies</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has solved my problem. I really need to read up on css positioning as it really confuses me. Thanks again.

Comment: @JackSmith Do read on it. It's part of the fundamentals of CSS. Understanding positionning, the box model, how margin and padding work, etc. is key to good CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below CSS:

```css
body {
  background: #e6eef2;
}

header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

.home-section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  float: left;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-main {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main ul {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.nav-main ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-main ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  top:20px;
  background: grey;
}
 .nav-main ul ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: #CCC;
}

.nav-main ul ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.nav-main ul ul li a {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-main ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.sub-nav {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

.sub-nav ul {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.sub-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.sub-nav ul li h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-nav ul li a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 482px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This and the below code snippets have both worked for me.

Comment: always happy to help and can you please upvote the answer.